# How to upload files without using FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, upload

I want to open file dialog on click of a button in asp.net without using file upload control. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML directly if you don't like server controls: `<input type="file" name="foo" />`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to open a browse dialog (short of using from client side plugin, such as a Java Applet) is to use the `file` type `input`:

```
<input type="file" name="somename" />
```

This is what the FileUpload control renders.

If you don't want to use that control, you can just use the direct HTML element.

Each browser will render this slightly differently though.